# Coldfusion array from form checkbox

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this. I have a series of form fields with checkboxes for people to select options. When that gets submitted it turns `form.optiongroups` into an array. I then check to see if the id of the `optiongroup` is in the array and set the checked value to true in case there were form errors I want them to retain their checked value. This all works fine.

If I only select one option though it doesn't come through as an array, but just a regular form field. Is there a way I can handle this to make sure it is always an array?

Comment: See `sameformfieldsasarray` https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, checkboxes get submitted as a list.  You must have something else going on that creates the array.

However, to answer your question as asked, you can use `ListToArray()`.  It would be something like this:

```
if (structkeyexists(form, 'optiongroups') { // if no boxes are checked the variable will be undefined.
    
    if (isArray(form.optiongroups) == false )
        form.optiongroups = ListToArray(form.optiongroups) 
    } else {  
        code for no boxes checked
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I was able to piece it together from this!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done via...

```
param form.optiongroups = "";

form.optiongroups = ListToArray(form.optiongroups);
```

Comment: If you want to use a param, why not use one command instead of two?  `param form.optiongroups = []`

Comment: Because it would throw an error when I run the `ListToArray` function